# SWIFT library calls not executing after code resign

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have an iOS project that has both objective-c and SWIFT code. Due to requirements for releasing an in-house build, I have to code resign. After code resigning, the calls to SWIFT library are not executing. Objective-C code executes. I am resigning the SWIFT library as well.

// Code resign Frameworks folder

```
BRANDINGFRAMEWORKSDIR=${BRANDINGAPPDIR}/Frameworks/*
codesign --force --verbose --sign "${BRANDSIGNINGIDENTITY}" ${BRANDINGFRAMEWORKSDIR}
```

// Code resign main app
codesign

`-s "${BRANDSIGNINGIDENTITY}" -f "${BRANDINGAPPDIR}/" --entitlements "${BRANDINGWORKINGDIR}/entitlements.plist"`

I am using the above instructions. Interestingly, this was working in Xcode 6.4, but broke when we moved to Xcode 7.

Any help or tips will be appreciated.

Comment: What are the symptoms of "not executing"?  ...errors?  ...?

Comment: There are no errors. All compiled SWIFT code gets executed, but any calls made in the SWIFT dynamic library are not getting called. For ex: NSLog works, but not print